# Passing a List through as a ParcelableArrayList

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

So hey guys, Im having some trouble with some code. Im implementing parcelables. Basically I have an List of items initiated globally as

```
private List<Movie> mMovieList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and I wish to pass this in as a parcellable to save the instance state upon rotation. I implement the saveOnInstanceState method and onCreate

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(MOVIE_KEY, (ArrayList< ? extends Parcelable >)mMovieList);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        mMovieList = (List<Movie>)savedInstanceState.get(MOVIE_KEY);
    }
}
```

Only problem is it throws an error and the error points to the outstate.putParcelableArrayList line.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

Does anyone know of a fix or a way around this? I tried googling and looking at other stackoverflow answers but couldnt find one that worked.

Here is the GitHub link to the project if anyone wants to look at its entirety, the methods mention above have not been committed yet.
https://github.com/Rykuno/Flix-Viewer

Comment: The Movie item in your repo is not Parcelable. Is that up to date? You can't parcel a list if the items stored in the list are not parcelable.

Comment: @Francesc The movie is currently implementing Parcelable on my local machine, just havent pushed anything yet, I can if it would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly Android doesn't "program to the interface". If the `List` is not an `ArrayList` then you'll have no choice but to create a new `ArrayList`. This isn't a big deal and can be done programmatically.

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    ArrayList<Movie> toSave = mMovieList instanceof ArrayList ?
        (ArrayList<Movie>)mMovieList : new ArrayList<Movie>(mMovieList);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(MOVIE_KEY, toSave);
}
```

Comment: You're awesome. Thanks so much for the explanation. It completely slipped for whatever reason that List is an interface and not a class =/. It works beautifully now!